# sqlite3 separate column for each day going back x days

Tags: sql, sqlite

### Setup

sqlite3 database

### Objective

Be able to look at client delivery over the last x days (not hardcoded as intend to update daily) with a breakdown by "client" and a separate column for each day, so I can review trends and convert into graphs if wanted.

Can someone confirm if there is an easier way to get the desired output without using a `JOIN` command or is `JOIN` the recommended approach?

### Issue

I understand how to get a generate date filter with `select "blah" from "table" where date = "a date"` but I can't quite understand how to be able to get the dates set up into different columns to view trending.

I could do this with a `JOIN` but I feel like there should be an easier way than doing this given all data sits within one table. I've tried to google for solutions/searched the bowels of youtube for a tutorial but must be searching the wrong words.

### Sample Data

```
Client|Delivery|Date
client1|112966214|2020-03-27
client1|83060443|2020-03-26
client1|78606234|2020-03-25
client1|60987586|2019-03-24
```

### Current Query

```
select Client, sum(select Delivery from table_data where Date = DATE('now')) from table_data group by Client;
```

Desired Output columns

```
    Client|Delivery where Date = Today's Date |Delivery where Date = Date -1 day|Delivery where Date = Date -2 days | Delivery where Date = Date -3 days
client1|112966214|83060443|78606234|60987586
```

Comment: Do you really want to sum over the column delivery or count? And what is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: @forpas I want to sum as the table is an aggregate of data. I've updated the post and sample data to give a clearer Idea of the final output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select Client,
  sum(case when Date = date('now') then Delivery end) [Today's Date],
  sum(case when Date = date('now', '-1 day') then Delivery end) [Delivery where Date = Date -1 day],
  sum(case when Date = date('now', '-2 day') then Delivery end) [Delivery where Date = Date -2 day],
  sum(case when Date = date('now', '-3 day') then Delivery end) [Delivery where Date = Date -3 day]
from table_data
group by Client
```